# Displaying a module in specific articles

Tags: module, articles, module-manager

I am new to joomla and I am not a joomla developer.

I need a plugin that let modules be displayed in specific articles.

I mean:

1. Specify some content IDs in module management page.
2. Then display the module only in those pages.

I have tested **NoNumber Advanced Module Manager** extension, but this extension has lots of options that I do not need, and it is such heavy that result in 500 error on my site.

Comment: If Advanced Module Manager (now Regular Labs not NoNumber) is causing issues with your site then there are already issues with your site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want to display the module inside a given module position of your template, or inside your article content.

## Module in Module Positions

**Joomla Core Module Manager** gives the ability to assign modules per menu item. This allows for some control over where and when to display a module. That control is based on the menu item id. For example you can have a Category Blog Menu Item to display articles of a category and assign a module to this menu item. That module will be displayed under this category blog and all the articlesof that category linked from there (usually they will be displayed under that same menu item id). This flexibility in displaying modules per article, becomes higher if you create pages with single article menu items for your articles. You will have total control over in which articles you will show your modules. However, there can be cases when this is not sufficient, and you need deeper control. Then here it comes the Regular Labs Advanced Module Manager (previously called NoNumber).

**Advanced Module Manager**, gives extended control over where to display a module, like select only certain articles, or categories, or articles of a category only when there is an article view, or dates and much more. Regarding being heavy, there have been cases of versions of that component that were creating some slow SQL queries, but those were fixed. I am using this extension in so many projects with no issues. It shouldn't be heavy or slow at the moment, and if you encounter such issues with this extension, then you should report that to the developer. The 500error can be also something related to your hosting environment.

## Module inside article content

In this case, you can go with the **[loadmodule](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)** joomla core plugin. You can load certain modules, or a "full stack" of modules sitting in a certain module position.

Inside your article use: `{loadmodule module, moduleTitle}` to load a specific module, or `{loadposition modulePostion}` to load all modules from a certain module position. You will have full control over which articles will display those modules.

Another way of doing this is by creating template overrides over the com_content/articles component. In your template overrides you can [**programatically load certain modules or module positions**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9070/displaying-more-articles-in-the-article-view/9982#9982) that will be called by default in your content views. The appearance of these modules will be also affected by modules assignments (and status, ACL settings) in module manager or Advanced module manager. But here you have one additional control, that is the direct logic you can use by writing php inside your article overrides.

### Further Reading on Template Overrides

- [**Layout Overrides in Joomla.**](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)
- [**How to override the output of Joomla core**](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)
- [**Understanding Output Overrides**](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)

Comment: I just need to load a module when a specific content is displaying!! it's a piece of cake in drupal but too difficult in joomla!

Comment: You can control which pages the module is displayed on via the Menu Assignment tab in the module settings.

Comment: @shekoufeh : Your comment didn't add more info than your initial question, in order to help us understand exactly what you want to do. The above approaches will cover most of the situations though. Usually when someone starts to use something new, there is always a level of difficulty or learning curve - whatever that level may be. I never encountered any difficulty to display a module where and when I wanted, so If you have a specific difficulty, first be patient, then please describe that with your exact needs, to see if we can help you further.

Comment: @avian, well what shekoufeh said for drupal wasn't anything special that needs more attention - nor it was offensive. The comment go Back to Drupal, why bother us... isn't constructive though in anyway.

Comment: @FFrewin : Agreed... I stand corrected...